# How to mount a remote FTP share as local folder/directory?

Tags: mount, ftp

I would like to mount a remote FTP share as local directory (or drive) on Cyanogenmod and be able to access it like it was a regular folder and browse files on it.

Ideally, an app would mount FTP as a folder and let me browse files in it outside of that app, but if it can be done without any app, it is also acceptable. The folder need to be browsable by any application afterwards.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe [SSHFSAndroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chaos9k.sshfsandroid)? It's alpha software so be ready for some bumps.

Answer (score 2):

This won't directly mount it as a drive but ASTRO File Manager can emulate that experience. It will give you the same experience it does for local filesystems but with a FTP file system.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro for the download.

Comment: The aim is to be able to browse files outside of that application like a regular folder, is this possible with Astro FM? If not, the answer is not correct sorry.

Comment: @AdnanDoric Sadly ASTRO can't do that. You could have a look at http://fuse.sourceforge.net/